# Renovate: update dependency with syntactically different semver tags

Tags: github, renovate

This is my first time setting something up with Renovate, so bear in mind I may be missing or misunderstanding some concepts.

I have been following https://joht.github.io/johtizen/automation/2022/08/03/keep-your-cpp-dependencies-up-to-date.html to integrate Renovate and CPM with a C++/CMake repo. As a first test, I've swapped out a dependency we had simply pasted verbatim into the repo, to see if Renovate can parse the relevant package lock file and recommend an update for this dependency.

The entry for this dependency is as follows:

```
CPMDeclarePackage(StandaloneASIO_Package
  NAME StandaloneASIO_Package
  VERSION 1.21.0
  GIT_TAG asio-1-21-0
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio
)
```

So far, I have managed to get Renovate to correctly parse the current version from this entry:

```
"customManagers": [
    {
        "customType": "regex",
        "fileMatch": [
            "(^|/)package-lock\\.cmake$"
        ],
        "matchStrings": [
            "CPMDeclarePackage\\s*\\(\\s*[\\s\\w\\W]*\\s+VERSION\\s*\"?(?<currentValue>[\\w\\.]+)\"?\\s+[\\s\\w\\W]*\\s+GIT_REPOSITORY\\s+\"?(?<depName>.*?[^0-9a-f\\s]+.*|.{1,4}?)\"?",
            "CPMDeclarePackage\\s*\\(\\s*[\\s\\w\\W]*\\s+GIT_REPOSITORY\\s+\"?\\s+(?<depName>.*?[^0-9a-f\\s]+.*|.{1,4}?)\"?[\\s\\w\\W]*\\s+VERSION\\s*\"?(?<currentValue>[\\w\\.]+)\"?"
        ],
        "datasourceTemplate": "github-tags"
    }
]
```

However, this is where I get stuck. The Renovate dashboard still raises the error: `Renovate failed to look up the following dependencies: Failed to look up github-tags package https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio.`

My assumption was that since this repo uses tags rather than releases to record new versions, and lives on GitHub, that the correct data source should be `github-tags`, but obviously this is not working. Unfortunately [Renovate's documentation](https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/datasource/github-tags/) on the `github-tags` data source lacks any useful information, so I have no idea how it is supposed to be used.

My first suspicion is that the tags use the format `asio-<major>-<minor>-<patch>` rather than the standard semver `v<major>.<minor>.<patch>`, so Renovate may be unable to parse any meaning from them. Perhaps there is a way to define a template for parsing the tags that would allow Renovate to understand them, but the only documentation I've come across is regarding [creating a whole new data source](https://secustor.dev/blog/renovate_custom_datasources/). I feel like this is probably overkill for what I need to do, and am having trouble understanding all of the different elements of that process anyway.

Is there a simple solution for what I need to do here?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: I don't think I did, but I'm no longer with the company where I was doing this work, so can't really follow up easily.

Answer (score 0):

If this is related to the tag, you can try using the `extractVersionTemplate` configuration.

Something like this:

```json
"extractVersionTemplate": "^asio-(?<version>.*)$"
```

---

Note that the template may also contain tokens extracted from `matchStrings` like:

```json
"extractVersionTemplate": "^{{{depName}}}-(?<version>.*)$"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go today and see if I have any success.

Comment: Looking at this more closely, I'm not convinced it's what I need. The match string extracts the version from the `VERSION` line because this uses dots as opposed to hyphens. If this version string is used in the template above, would this not create `asio-1.2.3` rather than `asio-1-2-3`, which is what I need? It seems to me like I'd have to be able to distinguish the individual major, minor and patch values in order to construct the correct tag name.

Comment: You're right. I think you'll have to play a bit with `extractVersionTemplate` and `extractVersionTemplate` to come to the exact thing you need.

Comment: Did you mean `extractVersionTemplate` and something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `matchStrings` and `extractVersionTemplate`

Comment: OK thanks, I'll dig deeper into the match strings documentation and see if I can come up with anything.